# Download wordpress core using bash script

Tags: bash, wordpress

Im trying to use bash script to download wordpress core in a specific directory, what I did is this:

```
#!/bin/bash

wp core download /var/www/public_html/
```

But Im getting this error:

```
Error: Failed to get url '/var/www/design-press.site/': Only HTTP(S) requests are handled..
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to specify the directory when using the WordPress CLI. Instead you go to the directory where the core is to be copied:

```
cd /var/www/public_html
sudo -u www-data wp core download
```

Using `sudo -u www-data` ensures the files are copied with the correct ownership.

From there, you can begin your WordPress installation.

Comment: That wouldnt work because the bash script where Im running the code is in in a different directory than the one where I want to download wordpress, therefore I need to specify the directory

Comment: You will want to download the `.tar.gz` and control the entire process, then 